# How to automatically insert text of each cell in column as a comment to another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have 2 columns. Let's call them column1 and column2. Both columns cells contain some text or empty. What I want to do is to insert the text of a cell in column2 as comment to a cell on same row in column1 and apply it to all rows.

For example, given a table like this:

[image]

the cell with `Text1` will have comment qith `Text4`:

[image]

and so on:

[image]

Comment: Close vote for being "too broad"? How is this too broad? It is a very specific question.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to Google it but only found answers involving VBA which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I think you're unlikely to find a solution for this that doesn't involve VBA.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid VBA? I'm 99.32% positive you won't be able to accomplish this without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data in **A1** through **B100**.  If you change your mind and would accept a macro-based solution, try this:

```
Sub CommentMaker()
    Dim A As Range, aa As Range

    Set A = Range("A1:A100")
    A.ClearComments

    For Each aa In A
        aa.AddComment
        aa.Comment.Text Text:=CStr(aa.Offset(0, 1).Value)
    Next aa
End Sub
```